# Calculating items in JSON using .length

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a piece of JSON data:

```
"links" : {
    "linkDetails" : [
        {
            "Name" : "Miss XYZ",
            "DateOfBirth" : "01/01/1901",
            "linkEntry" : [
                {
                    "Address": {
                        "HouseName": null,
                        "HouseNumber": "XX",
                        "PostCode": "XXX",
                        "Street": "XXXX",
                        "Town": "XXXXXX"
                    },
                    "Name" : "Mr ABC",
                    "DateOfBirth" : "10/06/1983",
                    "linkCurrent" : [
                        {
                            "EntryNumber" : "XXX",
                            "Date" : "15/06/2012",
                            "ConfirmedBy" : "Joe Bloggs & Co"
                        },
                        {
                            "EntryNumber" : "XXX",
                            "Date" : "15/06/2012",
                            "ConfirmedBy" : "Joe Bloggs & Co"
                        }
                       ],
                    "linkPrevious" : [
                        {
                            "EntryNumber" : "XXX",
                            "Date" : "03/04/2012",
                            "ConfirmedBy" : "Lakers & Co"
                        },
                        {
                            "EntryNumber" : "XXX",
                            "Date" : "03/04/2012",
                            "ConfirmedBy" : "Lakers & Co"
                        },
                        {
                            "EntryNumber" : "XXX",
                            "Date" : "03/04/2012",
                            "ConfirmedBy" : "Lakers & Co"
                        }
                      ]
                },
                {
                    "Address": {
                        "HouseName": null,
                        "HouseNumber": "AA",
                        "PostCode": "AAAAA",
                        "Street": "AAAAAA",
                        "Town": "AAAAAA"
                    },
                    "Name" : "Mrs UYGTF",
                    "DateOfBirth" : "10/06/1964",
                    "linkCurrent" : [
                        {
                            "EntryNumber" : "XXX",
                            "Date" : "15/06/2012",
                            "ConfirmedBy" : "Mont James"
                        },
                        {
                            "EntryNumber" : "XXX",
                            "Date" : "15/06/2012",
                            "ConfirmedBy" : "Mont James"
                        }
                       ],
                    "linkPrevious" : [
                        {
                            "EntryNumber" : "XXX",
                            "Date" : "03/04/2012",
                            "ConfirmedBy" : "PRAZLint"
                        }
                       ]
                },
                {
                    "Address": {
                        "HouseName": null,
                        "HouseNumber": "CC",
                        "PostCode": "CCCCC",
                        "Street": "CCCCCCCCC",
                        "Town": "CCCCC"
                    },
                    "Name" : "Mr HGF",
                    "DateOfBirth" : "10/06/1964",
                    "linkCurrent" : [
                        {
                            "EntryNumber" : "XXX",
                            "Date" : "15/06/2012",
                            "ConfirmedBy" : "Aria"
                        }
                       ],
                    "linkPrevious" : [
                        {
                            "EntryNumber" : "XXX",
                            "Date" : "03/04/2012",
                            "ConfirmedBy" : "MGM"
                        },
                        {
                            "EntryNumber" : "XXX",
                            "Date" : "03/04/2012",
                            "ConfirmedBy" : "MGM"
                        },
                        {
                            "EntryNumber" : "XXX",
                            "Date" : "03/04/2012",
                            "ConfirmedBy" : "MGM"
                        }
                       ]
                }
            ]
        },
```

I have a simple `ng-repeat` that loops through the above an displays the NAME and DOB:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="links in links">
    <td>{{links.linkDetails.Name}}</a></td>
    <td>(Date of Birth {{links.linkDetails.DateOfBirth}})</td>
    <td>{{links.linkDetails.linkEntry.linkCurrent.length }} current links found; {{links.linkDetails.linkEntry.linkPrevious.length }} previous links found</td>
</tr>
```

However, the `length` for current and previous is not populating.

Comment: Nothing should be populating.. `linkDetails` is an Array.

Comment: All of your data types are messed up, like @tymeJV said. Make sure you're aware of whats an array and an object in your structure.

Comment: @tymeJV - linkDetails is just a snippet of my JSON, the above only shows one example in my array.. I have nearly 40 items in linkDetails in my real file.

Comment: @OamPsy -- That's the point, you don't reference a specific item, you can't just say `Array.ObjectProperty` - you need `Array[ItemIndex].ObjectProperty`

Comment: You also probably want to do `ng-repeat-start="link in links"` instead of `ng-repeat-start="links in links"`.

Comment: @tymeJV - thanks for taking the time to explain this. Rather than using .length, can a JS function carry out this calculation?

Answer (score 1):

In your JSON "`links`" is an object, "`linkDetails`" is an array and "`linkEntry`" is an array too. In your angularjs code "`links`" is an array "`linkDetails`" and "`linkEntry`" are objects. You need to fix any of that.

You probably should go through "`linkDetails`" not "`links`"

Comment: thanks for taking the time to explain this. Rather than using .length, can a JS function carry out this calculation?

Comment: Yes you can use define $scope.getLength = function(){...} and then use it like this {{ getLength(links) }}